# java 'File' Object not making the directory and file

Tags: java, file-io

I was trying to make a directory and file using java with **File** object as:

```
import java.io.*;
class CreateFile{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File f = new File("File/handling/file1.txt");
        if(!f.exists())
           f.createNewFile();
    }
}
```

but its showing error (see below) and unable to make it, the path and file name doesn't existed before execution. I don't know where am I going wrong, someone please clarify whats the mistake and how to resolve it? It might be I need to know something about **File** object, so please do tell me...

See error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path
specified

    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:947)
    at CreateFile.main(CreateFile.java:6)
```

Comment: If you actively avoid the javadocs, you're -never- going to be an effective Java programmer. Learn to love the API documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: Thanks for taking it in such good spirit. Here's another piece of advice: you can configure whatever IDE you're using to be able to show the javadoc of a standard API class/method in the IDE itself. No google / bookmark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you that either there is no `File` directory relative to where you're running this, or there is but it doesn't have a `handling` subdirectory. In this case, [`exists`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists--) returns `false` and so you call [`createNewFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile--) to try to create the file, but the directory in which you're trying to create it doesn't exist, and so it throws an exception.

You can use [`mkdirs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs--) to create the directories if necessary, like so:

```
import java.io.*;
class CreateFile{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File f = new File("File/handling/file1.txt");
        if(!f.exists()) {
           f.getParentFile().mkdirs(); // This is a no-op if it exists
           f.createNewFile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the "File/handling" path doesn't existed but isn't the File object creates full directory/file path as "File/handling/file1.txt" ? I need to create the full path at run-time...

Comment: @AnkurShah: No, `createNewFile` does not create *directories*. It creates a *file*. If it can't, because you've told it to put the file somewhere that doesn't exist, it tells you that (via the exception). Hence the change above, ensuring the directories exist before trying to create the file.